# How to get characters like '┌' and '─' on ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, character

I have both Windows and Ubuntu on my computer, and I am using python3 on my Ubuntu.
I am pretty new with python programming, and here is the problem:

```
if access == 1:
print("\n" * 100)
print("┌──────────────────────────────┐")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("│                              │")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("│  Welcome to the Viktoracri   │")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("│       system database        │")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("│                              │")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("├──────────────────────────────┤")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("│                              │")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("│ Logged in as: %s             │" % u)
time.sleep(0.1)
print("│                              │")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("│ You are now logged in to the │")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("│ Viktoracri system database.  │")
time.sleep(0.1)
print("│
```

If this helps, I have this at the top of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

Those characters, '┐' and '│' does behave very strangly when I run the code.

[image]

Please help? The characters I have is from the Windows character map.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the character as a unicode character? Instead of putting the `┌` symbol in your code, try replacing it as `\u250c`. You may also find a solution here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: The other characters will need to be fixed as well, assuming this fixes your problem

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/python` ... This is python 2.x?

Comment: I think that you have a utf-8 encoded file and you are running python 2. When you do ` -*- coding: latin-1 -*-` python interprets those bytes as `latin-1` so you get garbage. When you view the file in a utf-8 editor ot terminal, it looks right. latin-1 doesn't even have those characters (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) though some of the variants likely do.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal is set to `latin-1` (or ISO-8859-1 on my box):

```
>>>print "├──────────────────────────────┤".decode('iso8859')
ââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââââ¤


>>>print "├──────────────────────────────┤".decode('utf8')
├──────────────────────────────┤
```

See the repl.it: [Python2](https://repl.it/IBUs/0) [Python3](https://repl.it/HjUB/1)

The fix is to change your terminal encoding so it displays the characters properly. I can replicate/fix your issue locally by swapping my terminal encoding between `utf-8` & `latin-1`

Comment: Fixed. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing the encoding of the stdout

```
import sys
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter('utf8')(sys.stdout)
```

if that doesn't work ,you may try changing the environment variable "PYTHONIOENCODING" to "utf_8."

Comment: `stdout` should be whatever encoding your terminal is. I don't see how passing a potentially improperly encoded stream to the terminal helps.

Comment: If you are using a different encoding , defining it should help. Well i think it should work but i cannot be sure as i am a Windows user.